# Correcting Pronunciation Errors in 'Say' Command in Terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, text-to-speech, voiceover

I'm having difficulty correcting the pronunciation in the 'say' command, using 10.9.

I tried to add new pronunciations through:

System Preferences > Dictation and Speech > Open Accessibility Preferences > Open VoiceOver Utility > Speech > Pronunciation > +

After I added a new entry I tried it in both Terminal and TextEdit and neither pronounced it correctly:

```
$ say -v "Samantha" -f filename.txt -o audiofile.aiff
```

Although it did not work in TextEdit (Edit > Speech > Start Speaking), I want to be able to accomplish this in Terminal.

Does anyone have any idea of how I can go about doing this?

Comment: right before you go to Pronunciation, in the Voices tab instead, is Samantha the Default voice? It might be that the training only works for the default.

Comment: Yes, 'she' is. Still can't seem to get this to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
# read.sh <file-to-read> [name-of-voice]
#!/bin/bash

textToRead=$(cat $1)

IFS=$'\n'
while read rep; do
        IFS=" "
        repArray=( $rep )
        textToRead=${textToRead//${repArray[0]}//${repArray[1]}}
done < replacements.txt

if [ -z $2 ]; then
        echo "$textToRead" | say
else
        echo "$textToRead" | say -v $2
fi
```

This shell script read replacements from `replacements.txt` and uses the say command to read the files content after replacing what's defined in `replacements.txt`.

`replacements.txt`: One line per replacement, `<search> <replace>`.

Sorry for the ugly code... I hate bash scripting.

Comment: This is amazing! Thank you very much for taking the time to write this!

Answer (score 3):

According to [this 2007 thread at discussions.apple.com](https://discussions.apple.com/message/4988176#4988176) the VoiceOver utility only fixes pronunciations in VoiceOver itself, not in text-to-speech.

So if you want to get `say` to correctly pronounce the words you should run a find and replace on the text file for each mis-pronounced word. *There is probably a good way to do this in one step with a script*, but if you just want to do it once you could:

1. Open the file in Text Edit (or any text editor you prefer, I like Text Wrangler)
2. Find (e.g.) "women" and replace all with "wimmen" (Located at `Edit > Find > Find and Replace...` in Text Edit)
3. Move to the next word you want to correct finding and replacing all until you've corrected all the mispronunciations.
4. Run `say` on the now incorrectly spelled text file.

Comment: Thanks. What would be the best way to do this? Would it be finding and replacing each mispronounced word using sed or is there a better way? Just out of curiosity, is there even a dictionary lookup tool available somewhere?

Comment: you could probably build up a sed command that does all the find and replace in one line and then save that as a bash script. As you find new mispronunciations you could then just edit the script.